# sass sourcemaps gulp task setup

Tags: sass, gulp

I have my sass gulp task to compile my initial css:

```
var input = './sass/bootstrap/*.scss';
var output = './public/css';


var sassOptions = {
     lineNumbers: true
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp
        // Find all `.scss` files from the `stylesheets/` folder
        .src(input)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass(sassOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
});
```

Then in a seperate project I have my watch task to minify the css:

```
gulp.task('debug-css', function () {
gulp.src([
        'assets/css/style.test.css',
        'assets/css/other.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
livereload.listen();
gulp.watch('assets/**/*.css', function() {
    gulp.src([
            'assets/css/style.test.css',
            'assets/css/other.css'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
});
```

When I use chrome dev tools, I cannot see the sass partials anywhere, Is there a way I can setup sourcemaps so I can tell which css comes from which sass file?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is good with your sourcemaps, you should try to separate a bit more the gulp.task and gulp.watch you've created so avoiding to confuse yourself.

I recreated your Gulpfile, adding some more useful plugins, here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/carlosbensant/2a3a36633a06a50dda775b2a8bde3958

**Working with Sourcemaps**

Said that, if you want to see the sourcemaps while you're in development stage you just have to run `gulp`; when you just want to deploy you're app then you should run `gulp css` to remove the sourcemaps into the CSS compiled (and so saving file space).

**Recommendation**

Try to BrowserSync, after some years using LiveReload, when I used BrowserSync the first time, I didn't get back to LiveReload, because it does a lot more than just live reloading. One of the coolest thing it does is synchronizing between multiple browsers (and platforms).

Hope that helps!